# SelectedIndex for List<int>

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

```
List<int> megalist;
int boxId;
boxId = ListofUniqueIDSpecificToDate.IndexOf(lstbox.SelectedIndex);<< this is wrong
```

I'm trying to display the ID inside megalist by making use of the selected index on lstbox

meaning , if is select the first item on lstbox , it will load the first item on megalist

Comment: What is actually in your list box?  `SelectedIndex` gives you the index in the collection displayed by the list box, it may or may not correspond with your other list. What is `ListofUniqueIDSpecificToDate` supposed to be in relation to `megalist` and `lstbox`?

Comment: Well, i have a list of Object and would like to load them specifically. What i have done is use the index selected from the List the user has selected to retrieve the specific item in that list which is in a proper order. Its in sequence , so corresponding isnt a problem.

Comment: I'm looking for something like istofUniqueIDSpecificToDate.SELECTEDINDEX

Comment: Edit your question with some additional code like what is ListofUniqueIDSpecificToDate etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m assuming you want to retrieve the `i`<sup>th</sup> item from your `ListofUniqueIDSpecificToDate` collection, where `i` corresponds to the index of the selected item in your `lstbox`.

In that case, you need to use list indexers, `[i]` (provided that `ListofUniqueIDSpecificToDate`’s type implements the `IList<T>` interface).

```
boxId = ListofUniqueIDSpecificToDate[lstbox.SelectedIndex];
```

`IndexOf(obj)`, on the other hand, would retrieve the index of the first element along the collection whose value is equal to `obj`.